# MySQL Query and JOINS

Tags: mysql, left-join, relationship

I haven't been able to figure out how to make this query work.

I have a table for people and their personal data.
I have a table of *let's call it houses*

Let's say that the tables have these fields:

```
PEOPLE
id, code, name, lastname

HOUSES
id, codeowner, codeintermediate, codebuyer, area, numberofrooms
```

If I have three columns with a relationship with the same table (people) how can I make a LEFT JOIN work?

If owners, intermediates and buyers were separated I would use something like

```
"SELECT
houses.*,

owners.name AS ownersname,
intermediates.name AS intermediatesname,
buyers.lname AS buyersname
FROM houses
LEFT JOIN owners ON houses.codeowner = owners.code
LEFT JOIN intermediates ON houses.codeintermediate = intermediates.code
    LEFT JOIN buyers ON houses.codebuyer = buyers.code
```

But how can I make this work with a single PEOPLE table? How can I use the aliases and so? Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the people table 3 times

```
SELECT
houses.*,

owners.name AS ownersname,
intermediates.name AS intermediatesname,
buyers.name AS buyersname
FROM houses
LEFT JOIN people as owners ON houses.codeowner = owners.code
LEFT JOIN people as intermediates ON houses.codeintermediate = intermediates.code
LEFT JOIN people as buyers ON houses.codebuyer = buyers.code
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, I just didn't know you could do this. Thank you!